# Change data directory when creating MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to store some MySQL tables in my external hard drive as the tables would contain a large amount of data (I would like to keep my default data directory and just store a couple of tables in the external HDD). I tried below query while creating a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE clients
(
  client_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT KEY,
  client_name VARCHAR(75),
  telephone CHAR(15)
)
DATA DIRECTORY = 'alternate directory';
```

However, I get below error:

```
[2021-02-20 12:10:36] [HY000][3121] The DATA DIRECTORY location must be in a known directory.
[2021-02-20 12:10:36] [HY000][3121] The DATA DIRECTORY location must be in a known directory.
[2021-02-20 12:10:36] [HY000][1031] Table storage engine for 'clients' doesn't have this option
```

I am using `mysql  Ver 8.0.23 for osx10.16 on x86_64 (Homebrew)`.

How can i solve this issue? If there is any other way to store MySQL tables in custom location, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-create-table-external.html. Looks like you need InnoDB, and you need to get some settings right. innodb_directories, innodb_file_per_table in particular.

Comment: I added the directory to innodb_directories but now it shows me ``Got error 168 - 'Unknown (generic) error from engine' from storage engine``

Comment: I'd check that the mysql user has permission to write to that location, and I'd try it using a different location on a non-external drive first, in case there's a difference. Also check the mysql error log, which might have proper information (https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-19849)

Comment: Yes a non-external drive works. Would you have any suggestion on how to check mysql read permission on external drive? I have set 'chown 777' for the external drive

Comment: Use something like `su -c 'touch /path/to/dir/file' mysqluser` and see what happens.

Comment: umm.. I have set the hdd folder permission as 'drwxrwxrwx'. I can't use su command. But using sudo, it seems terminal can't execute the command.

Comment: `sudo -s` might work in place of `su -c`. You might need to look at the mysql error log as well. I'm not sure I'm going to be able to help any further. You'll need info from logs.

Comment: mysql error log says, ``2021-02-20T18:09:40.217770Z 8 [ERROR] [MY-012596] [InnoDB] Error number 1 means 'Operation not permitted'
2021-02-20T18:09:40.217810Z 8 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File /Volumes/nasifhdd/mysql_data/openmrsvd: 'mkdir' returned OS error 101`` Thanks for your help till now. Not sure how to make mysql work on external hdd

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150707/mysql-tables-on-external-hard-drive